# mod_rewrite: Hiding PHP extension and showing querystrings as directories

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have files with the extension `.php` and I'd like to hide them, as well as show querystrings as inner directories of the rewritten PHP extension.

In other words, I'd like `https://domain.com/page.php`

to be accessed with `https://domain.com/page/` (with the ending slash) and for

`https://domain.com/page/?id=1` to be accessed with

`https://domain.com/page/1/` (also with the ending slash)

I'd also like access to the page with the `.php` extension return a 404 not found.

How would I do this in the `.htacess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTACCESS would need to look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]+)/([1-0]+)/$ $1.php?page=$2
```

For the custom 404 Error you would use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

However you will need to make sure that you apply the first rewrite rule to the 404 page.
You will need a `404.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [mod_rewrite rule generator](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml). If you want to write the rules yourself, it's fairly simple: it uses the same regular expressions as the PHP preg_* functions do :)

In your particular instance, use `RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]+)/([1-0]+)/$ $1.php?page=$2`